# How to find corresponding setters and getters?

Tags: reflection, dart, dart-mirrors

Using the dart:mirrors library how can I find all corresponding getters and setters for any class mirror.

```
class Person {
  String _name;
  Person(this._name);
  String get name => _name;
  set name (String value) {_name = value;}
}
```

In this example I'd like to find "name" setter and getter methods to group them without any prior knowledge about the class.

Is there a way to do this properly? Or should I hack my way through using class mirror's instanceMembers, perhaps converting setters symbols to strings or something like that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can list getters and setters like this:

```
import 'dart:mirrors';

class Person {
  String _name;
  Person(this._name);
  String get name => _name;
  set name (String value) {_name = value;}
  void bar() {

  }
}

void main() {
  ClassMirror mirror = reflectClass(Person);
  mirror.declarations.forEach((Symbol symbol, DeclarationMirror declaration) {
    if(declaration is MethodMirror) {
      if(declaration.isSetter) {
        print('setter: ' + MirrorSystem.getName(declaration.simpleName));
      }

      if(declaration.isGetter) {
        print('getter: ' + MirrorSystem.getName(declaration.simpleName));
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Output:

```
getter: name
setter: name=
```

Is that what you need? I don't think you can do it in a different way.

I don't think you can directly get the variable (_name). You can use `declaration.source` to get the source code. maybe you can do some splitting here. :)

Does this help?

Regards,
Robert

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about doing something like this to build a Map of getters then reiterate again on the mirror's declarations to find corresponding setters. So for a _setter_ the corresponding _getter_ key would be  MirrorSystem.getName(setterMethodMirror.simpleName).replaceAll('=', ''). I was wondering if there was another way.

Comment: I don't think there is :)